# Explicitly specified type 'NSURL?' issue while updating to Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, nsurl

I am having issues while updating my iOS app's code to the latest version of Swift.

I have a function:

```
public class func gifWithURL(gifUrl:String) -> UIImage? {
    // Validate URL
    guard let bundleURL:NSURL? = NSURL(string: gifUrl)
        else {
            print("SwiftGif: This image named \"\(gifUrl)\" does not exist")
            return nil
    }

    // Validate data
    guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: bundleURL! as URL) else {
        print("SwiftGif: Cannot turn image named \"\(gifUrl)\" into NSData")
        return nil
    }

    return gifWithData(data: imageData)
}
```

And am getting a warning on the following line:

```
guard let bundleURL:NSURL? = NSURL(string: gifUrl)
```

and am getting the warning:

> Explicitly specified type 'NSURL?' adds an additional level of optional to the initializer, making the optional check always succeed

Xcode allows me to fix the problem automatically. When I do this auto-fix, my code changes to:

```
guard let bundleURL:NSURL NSURL(string: gifUrl)
```

Which is obviously not the correct syntax.

I am unsure what I need to add/remove to get my code fully up to date with Swift 3 standards and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSURL(string:)` will return optional `NSURL?` instance and you are already optionally wrapping it with `guard` so remove the `: NSURL?` because you are setting it again `optional` instead of `non-optional` also, in Swift 3 use native [`URL`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url) and [`Data`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data) instead of `NSURL` and `NSData`. The whole code would be like.

```
guard let bundleURL = URL(string: gifUrl), let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: bundleURL) else {
     print("SwiftGif: This image named \"\(gifUrl)\" does not exist")
     return nil
}
//Access the imageData here
```

**Note:** [`Data(contentsOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779617-init) will `throws` exception so you need to catch it using `do try catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it too complicated. In Swift 3, we don't use `NSURL`. It's just `URL`:

```
guard let bundleURL = URL(string: gifUrl) else {
    print("SwiftGif: This image named \"\(gifUrl)\" does not exist")
    return nil
}
```

Then you can also get rid of your dangerous force-cast:

```
guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: bundleURL) else {
    print("SwiftGif: Cannot turn image named \"\(gifUrl)\" into NSData")
    return nil
}
```